# iOS - Couldn't launch app, failed to get the task for process 86757

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I am working on an iOS app for my office. If I disable the `Debug executable` option from `Edit Scheme` the app runs on the device perfectly. But In that mode, no breakpoints work for debugging. But If I enable the `Debug executable` the app shows the above error. All I want is to run the app and also debug it at the same time. Does anyone have any idea? I saw a lot of posts related to this error and the uncheck of `Debug executable` worked but I need the breakpoints thing. Thanks in advance
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using an Adhoc profile instead of a Development profile. Creating a development profile and using it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this approach](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/114699) from Apple's forum:

> This info solved it for me:
> https://developer.apple.com/support/expiration/
> Apparently apple issued a new certificate to sign apps with, xcode versions that are 'too old' don't automatically add this new certificate to the
> keychain. I had to manually download the new certificate and drop it
> in the KeyChain (Keychains: login, category: certificates). I didn't
> change anything to the scheme and also didn't delete or fix any
> certificates..

By the way, there's a temporary workaround could be helpful (also mentioned in the link above) - change *Launch* parameter to *Ask on Launch*

Answer (score 0):

because you have not added that device UDID so add it and create your certificates again